# How to display state this.appRef.isStable in template?

Tags: angular, angular6, angular8

I have tried this:

```
public state$: Observable<boolean>;
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.state$ = this.appRef.isStable;
}
```

Template is:

```
{{ state$ | async }}
```

This does not work for me

Comment: What does this.appRef.isStable hold?

Comment: It holds observable<boolen>

Comment: Does it throw any error?

Comment: Boolean might not get displayed in the html. Try with a number or string, or check the condition in html and render some text

Comment: @SharanMohandas: Why won't a boolean get displayed in the template? Could you please elaborate?

Comment: My bad, I remember encountering something like that.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ken44e 

@Jessy this seems to work

Comment: What is in the console log?